# MYSQL select, set all negative values to zero

Tags: php, mysql

Let assume I have mysql table called "test" in this table I have two columns "A", "B".
 I want to get the result of A-B, but for each row that the result is negative, I want to set it to zero.

So I can write :
select test.A - test.B as myResult

But I don't know how to set myResult to zero when myResult  is negative number.
Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select case when test.A - test.B >= 0 then test.A - test.B else 0 end as myResult from test;
```

Answer (score 7):

Why always making things complicated?

Just use the built in functions for such issues:

```
select greatest(0, test.A-test.B) as myResult from test;
```

From the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest

Comment: that would return a 0 whenever his result is positive.  He wants a zero only when it is negative.  Also, wouldn't this return negative numbers, which is what he is trying to avoid?

Comment: Oh, you're right.. my mistake.. I meant `greatest()` instead of `least()`. THX

Answer (score 5):

Use the `IF` statement to set it to zero when it's negative.

```
SELECT a, b, IF(a-b<0,0,a-b) as myResult FROM test;
```

This only does that to your query results, it doesn't actually `UPDATE` the table.